# ColdFusion insert multiple records checkboxes, not looping through hidden fields

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I have a field with multiple checkboxes on it, dynamically populated from a database query.  For example, let's say there are 6 checkboxes, and I select 2 of them.  The insert code is working fine, but it only passes ONE TestCategoryID and ONE TestID, even though the checkbox options might be from different categories and all have different test numbers. If I include the hidden fields in the main query output within the form, then I get an error that says the number of fields and values don't match, and it doesn't insert anything. Here is my form.

```
<form action="form_processor.cfm" method="post" name="testdefaults" id="testdefaults">
    <table width="50%" align="center">
    <cfoutput query="getMasterTests">
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input name="MasterID" type="checkbox" value="#MasterID#" /> 
            <span class="small-font">#TestCategoryID# #TestCategory# | #TestID# #SUBTEST# (#MasterID#)</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </cfoutput>
    </table>
    <div align="center" style="padding: 22px;">
      <input name="save" type="submit" class="myButton" value="Save Selected Tests as YOUR Default Tests" />
    </div>
    <cfoutput>
    <input name="TestCategoryID" type="hidden" value="#getMasterTests.TestCategoryID#" />
    <input name="TestID" type="hidden" value="#getMasterTests.TestID#" />
    <input name="userID" type="hidden" value="#getUser.RegistrationID#" />
    </cfoutput>  
    <input type="hidden" name="MM_InsertRecord" value="testdefaults" />
</form>
```

Here is my insert code:

```
<cfloop INDEX="Checked_ITEM" LIST="#Form.MasterID#">
    <cfquery Name="add" DataSource="mvqs">
        INSERT INTO tblXLU_Test_Defaults (Default_User_ID, TestCategoryID, TestID, MasterID)
        VALUES (#form.UserID#, #Form.TestCategoryID#, #Form.TestID#, '#Checked_ITEM#')
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

I need to be able to loop through not only the Master ID of the checkbox, which works, but also the TestCategoryID and TestID fields as well, and I'm stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You only need to write to two columns in the tblXLU_Test_Defaults table.   1) MasterID and 2) Default_user_ID.

Given a MasterID, your database already knows which TestID and TestCategoryID are associated with it.  You don't need to save this data yet again.

If you REALLY wanted to save these additional fields into that tblXLU_Test_Defaults table anyway, you could look up that information with a SELECT query in your insert code, using the MasterID as a reference.

Comment: You're right!  I was making it too complicated.  Thank you!  :)

Comment: Please note:  You really, really need to use <cfqueryparam>.  Unprotected SQL commands are very susceptible to hacking.  While it's not an answer to your question, seems you have that already, its very important to let you know.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  :)

Comment: For the hidden fields, you have a simple `cfoutput` tag and your values come from a query.  The way ColdFusion executes that code is to get the values from the first row of the query.